# In django admin, how to get form data in custom method

Tags: django, django-modeladmin

I search to retrieve form data (in case of change view) in a ModelAdmin class custom method :

Here what i want to be able to do :

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def custom_method(self):
        pprint(self.data['myfield'])
```

I can't change custom_method prototype.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is this custom_method called? You may also need to pass the object.

Comment: No it's not possible to do that.